# Exponential Notation for Octal

Tags: c, hex, octal

- Compiler: GCC 4.7.2(Debian 4.7.2-5)
- Platform: Linux 3.2.0 x86 (Debian 7.1)

I am writing a string to integer conversion function and I read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal#Hexadecimal_exponential_notation) that hexadecimal has it's own form of exponential notation. I have a couple questions regarding that.

1. The article says that the value that follows the 'p' is a decimal not a hexadecimal is that correct?
2. The article also says that power that comes after the 'p' has a base of 2 not 16 is that true?
3. Is `0x1.11p4` an integer or does it have a fractional component?

And this leads to the main question: does octal have it's own form of exponential notation? If it does, what is the form?

If octal does *not* have it's own exponential notation, would it be reasonable to adapt the hexadecimal notation to octal strings as well?

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your question: you think you need your conversion routine to be able to handle a string containing octal numbers in exponential notation, and convert them to the correct integer. Is that right?

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to reinvent `strtol` rather than just using `strtol` itself?

Comment: jwodder no not any reason at all and @Floris yes I want to convert a string containing an octal number to an integer and if the octal numeral system has some form of exponential notation I want to handle that as well.

Comment: @JohnVulconshinz You'll be pleased to know that your octal number handling just got easier =)

Comment: For what it's worth, I have never actually seen anyone use exponential notation with octal or hexadecimal. While it does *exist* for hexadecimal, it's largely a curiosity - floating-point numbers are almost univerally entered and printed in decimal.

Comment: @paddy that was an excellent comment!

Comment: C has no octal exponential notation, either for literals or for any of its standard functions.

Comment: @duskwuff: Hexadecimal floating-point is useful for representing floating-point numbers exactly. `0x1.921fb54442d18p+1` is shorter than `3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875`

Comment: While it *is* shorter, it's not like space in your source files is at a premium!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you have a healthy mistrust of Wikipedia! =)

1. Yes, the exponent is decimal.
2. Yes, the base is 2, not 16.
3. 0x1.11p4 is equivalent to 11.1<sub>16</sub> and is a float, not an integer.

I don't know of an octal form.  If you wished to define your own I don't see a problem with that.  Presumably you would use a `0` prefix instead of `0x` and leave everything else the same.  Obviously you can't write code with this representation, since the compiler doesn't support it.

Comment: `0x1.11p4` isn't quite 11.1 in base 16, it's actually 1.11 in base 16, multiplied by 16 (2 to the power of 4).

Answer (score 3):

- The value that follows the `p` is in decimal, but it represents an exponent with base 2.
- `0x1.11p4` has a fractional component of `.11` which is also in base 16.
- There are no octal floating point constants, so you cannot use exponential notation with them.
- To clarify with your example, `0x1.11p4` is 1.11<sub>16</sub> × 2<sup>4</sup>.